# Netty 4.1 - Detect Reject Connection caused full connection

Tags: netty

I have implementation Netty 4.1 as TCP Server to handler thousand of client, but don't know how to detect if server can't receive client caused connection is full, so application notify administrator that server is full, in traditional ServerSocket we can detect exception too many connection / too many open files:

```
public class TCPServer {
    
    private int port;
    
    public TCPServer (int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    
    public void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new FrameDecoder());
                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProcessingData());

                 }
             })
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)         
             .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
    
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 9812;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        new TCPServer
(port).run();
    }
}
```

Frame Decoder also as detect connection is full

```
public class FrameDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    public FrameDecoder() {
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        try {
            ctx.fireExceptionCaught(cause);
            // i never get exception like too many open files here....
            //
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

   @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        if (buf.readableBytes() < 5) {
            return;
        }
        int length = 2 + 2; // head and tail

        if (buf.getByte(buf.readerIndex()) == 0x78 && buf.getByte(buf.readerIndex() + 1) == 0x78) {
            length += 1 + buf.getUnsignedByte(buf.readerIndex() + 2);
        } else{
            length += 2 + buf.getUnsignedShort(buf.readerIndex() + 2);
        }

        if (buf.readableBytes() >= length && buf.getUnsignedShort(buf.readerIndex() + length - 2) == 0x0d0a) {
            out.add(buf.readRetainedSlice(length));
            return;
        }
        int endIndex = buf.readerIndex() - 1;
        do {
            endIndex = buf.indexOf(endIndex + 1, buf.writerIndex(), (byte) 0x0d);
            if (endIndex > 0 && buf.writerIndex() > endIndex + 1 && buf.getByte(endIndex + 1) == 0x0a) {
                out.add(buf.readRetainedSlice(endIndex + 2 - buf.readerIndex()));
            }
        } while (endIndex > 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a `ChannelInboundHandler` for the `ServerChannel` via `b.handler(...)`. The `childHandler(...)` adds handlers for the "accepted" `Channel`s, while `handler(...)` adds handlers for the `ServerChannel` that accept the `Channel`s. As the exception is thrown for the `ServerChannel` you will need to handle it there and not on the child handler.